# using Tornado's WSGIContainer, how do I make it run in debug mode so I get better error messages

Tags: python, flask, tornado

I am writing a Flask web app that uses Tornado as its web server. When my application raises an exception, I get the unhelpful error message "Internal Server Error". I want it to instead display the stack trace, so i can see what is going wrong.

The Tornado manual says I can do this if I pass `debug=True` to the `Application` constructor. However I am not using the `Application` constructor, instead I am using a `WSGIContainer`. Here is my source code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    container = wsgi.WSGIContainer(main.app)
    http_server = httpserver.HTTPServer(container) 
    http_server.listen(8210)
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

How do I get Tornado to output stack information on errors?

Answer (score 0):

`WSGIContainer` does not have this feature. You may be able to get it with WSGI middleware instead of from the container; otherwise you'll need to use a different server for developing the Flask portions of your application.

Note that if your application is entirely flask-based, using Tornado's WSGIContainer is a bad idea - it's much less scalable than the alternatives. WSGIContainer is only useful in the case when you need to mix two frameworks in one process and are willing to pay the price in features and scalability. See the warning at http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/wsgi.html#tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer